# Bootstrap button on master page doesn't shows up on content page

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, master-pages

I dont know what I am doing wrong but a simple bootstrap button on master page doesnt shows up in content page. I am including the right css on header of master page.

My master page looks like this
[image]

and content page looks like this

[image]

I don't understand what I am missing here.

Comment: Your anchor is inside the content placeholder of the master page. Move any content you want on every page outside the placeholder or inside the placeholder of a specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContentPlaceHolder` in the `MasterPage` gets entirely replaced by the `Content` specified in the page. That anchor tag you added to the master page is just getting overwritten.

To solve this, either

1. Move the anchor tag outside of the `ContentPlaceHolder` on the `MasterPage`, making it visible on all pages that use the masterpage, or
2. Move the anchor tag inside the `Content` tag on the page, making it visible on this page only.

Answer (score 1):

A ContentPlaceHolder control isn't used to put content on your master page it's used to mark a section within your master page that your Content control on your page can render content in.

To fix your issue either move your anchor tag from the ContentPlaceHolder control and place it outside if you want it shared across all pages that use the master page, or move the anchor tag from your ContentPlaceHolder control and place it inside your Content control on your page if you wasn't it specific to Default.aspx.

Further reading on master pages and content place holders: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx